# Django App Display No Result

Tags: django

I'm working on an app called Start the dark from the tutorial django from ground up.
I have just started on the tutorial and I have difficulty displaying the result on html.

The app is suppose to display the description of the event . The creator of the  event and the time it was posted and when I type the link . It's display nothing.

I spent few hours troubleshooting and so far I learn't the problem is  not my html form either it's my URL cause I did some test. I think it's getting the results from the models.py into my views.py and executing it

My models.py are :

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet


 class Event(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank= True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User , related_name = 'event_creator_set')
    attendees = models.ManyToManyField(User , through = "Attendance")
    latest = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        now = datetime.now()
        start = datetime.min.replace(year = now.year , month=now.month,day=now.day)
        end = (start + timedelta(days=1)) - timedelta.resolution
        Event.objects.filter(latest=True, creator=self.creator).filter(creation_date__range=(start,end)).update(latest=False)
    super(Event,self).save(**kwargs)

class Attendance(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s is attending %s" %(self.user.username,self.event)
```

My views.py

```
 from events.models import Event
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def tonight(request):
    events = Event.objects.filter(latest=True)
    return render_to_response('events/tonight.html',{'events':events},context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

My tonight.html

```
 {% if events %}
 <ul>
{{events.description}}
{{events.start_date}}
{{events.creator}}
 </ul>
 {% endif %}
```

My events URL.CONF

```
 from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
 from django.contrib import admin
 from events import views
 urlpatterns = patterns('events.views',
         url(r'^tonight/$','tonight',name='ev_tonight')
 )
```

My main URLconf

```
  from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
  from django.contrib import admin
  from django.conf import settings
  from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
  from django.conf.urls.static import static
  # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
  # from django.contrib import admin
  admin.autodiscover()
  urlpatterns = patterns('',

      url(r'^events/',include('events.urls')),



  ) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

  urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Some other models.

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.contrib import admin
 class student(models.Model):
         First_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
         Last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     Age = models.BigIntegerField()
     Body = models.TextField()

     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.First_name
```

Comment: your def unicode in your views must be in the models

Comment: oh okay. I see that mistake. thank you @catherine

Comment: @catherine I'll send you my app soon and you can help me with it when your free . You said you were going to make a social auth? what do you mean by social auth? Thank you for helping me :]

Comment: login/register via facebook, twitter, google, and more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here events is a queryset. Refer [django docs on querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/). You need to iterate over the objects in it. Edit your template code like this;

```
{% if events %}
    {% for each_event in events %}
        <ul>
            {{each_event.description}}
            {{each_event.start_date}}
            {{each_event.creator}}
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Because it's a queryset . I need to alway iterate over it?@arulmr

Comment: Yes. Whenever a queryset is passed to the template, it will iterate to get the objects in it.

Comment: I posted another model.py at the bottom. Is that also an queryset?

Comment: Yes. Refer the link in my answer. Every list of objects fetched using `.filter()` or `.all()` is a queryset.